# How to handle multiple pop-ups

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am writing a selenium test for the following flow:

1. Select all items.
2. Click on the Run button - opens a pop-up with two buttons "Proceed" and "Cancel".
3. Click on "Proceed", opens the new pop-up which will display the progress bar.

Here are two problems I am facing:

1. I am able to click the "Proceed" button via selenium code, but the moment it gets clicked the other pop-up which displays the progress bar doesn't show up, because of thisthe selenium is not able to identify the element. **How can I handle this?**
2. The Progress bar has one button "Cancel", while the progress bar is being filled the Value of the button remains "Cancel", but after it reaches 100% the Value changes to "Close". **How should I handle this?**

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

1. Tried to wait until the `visibiltyOfElement`, `presenceOfElement` of the element (progress bar) by XPath and id.
2. Tried `Thread.currentThread.sleep` after clicking "Proceed" and Implicit wait too.
3. Tried to wait until `AlertIsPresent`.

The code:

```
// Select all items 
wd.findElement(By.id("ListSelectAll")).click(); 
// click on Add the selected 
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='ListRunLink']/img")).click(); 
// Proceed to confirm Adding 
wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='Proceed']")).click(); 
// Wait until the Progress Bar Gets Displayed using the buttons 
// present in the Progress bar to address Wait!! 
wt.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Close']‌​"))); 
// The above code does NOT work - "not able to locate element with id CLOSE"
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: //Select all items
wd.findElement(By.id("ListSelectAll")).click();

//click on Add the selected
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='ListRunLink']/img")).click();

//Proceed to confirm Adding

wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='Proceed']")).click();

//Wait until the Progress Bar Gets Displayed using the buttons //,present in the Progress bar to address Wait!!

wt.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Close']")));

//Above Code NOT Working >>>not able to locate element with id CLOSE

Comment: It would be great if you could include the relevant piece of the HTML markup into your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I was doing one mistake after step1
i.e post clicking select all I was not checking whether the checkboxes are checked or not thus due to which, post clicking on the proceed there were no items to load thus the progress bar pop up was not showing up.
thus placed Thread.sleep(1000)
tried implicit and explicit waits but only thread.sleep came to savior
is their any better way to deal ???
Though still while debugging I came across one more question , in case the check boxes have dynamic id's how can i check if the 1st check box is checked or not, after click on select all??